# Yii Framework: authenticate user at many levels

Tags: php, yii

I'm newbie in Yii Framework.

I see Yii has Yii::app()->user->isGuest
It just check you are login or not.

I want to check user is guest or admin or member ... to show others info and permission.
Please help me.

Any help will be appreciate.Thank you.

Comment: Lets googling: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/191/implementing-a-user-level-access-system/

Answer (score 1):

Yii - Role based access control

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/328/simple-rbac/

Answer (score 1):

Yii - Rbac

yii doc: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#role-based-access-control

Hope this helps